# Como cambiar estilos en el HTML usando JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom

me piden como ejercicio que cambie varias cosas en un HTML utilizando solo JavaScript.
El punto es que hay 3 funciones que no me responden, no se que estoy haciendo mal.
Si alguno podría ayudarme lo agradezco.

Dejo el código que no me funciona:

Acá debería cambiar el tamaño de la fuente del párrafo utilizando el ID:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var tamaño = document.getElementById('destacado');
    tamaño.style.fontSize = 24;
</script>
```

El siguiente debería cambiar el color de la fuente de todos los párrafos:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementsByTagName('p').style.color='#0ca001';
</script>
```

Y el último que no funciona debería cambiar el tipo de fuente de los h2:

```
    <script>
function FontChange(){
    document.getElementsByTagName('h2').style.FontChange ='Arial';
}  
</script>
```

Intenté de las formas que conozco y leí pero nada responde.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primer ejercicio. debes poner un string en vez de un numero.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tamaño = document.getElementById('destacado');
    tamaño.style.fontSize = "24px"; // tienes que poner  24 entre comillas (un string) y especificar la unidad, ej: px, rem ...
</script>
```

Segundo ejercicio.
getElementsByTagName devuelve un HTMLCollection, el cual no tiene la propiedad style. Hazlo asi:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var parrafos = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    
    //convertir  la coleccion de parrafos a un array y luego aplicar el color a cada
    //parrafo
    Array.from(parrafos ).forEach( (p) => {
        p.style.color = '#0ca001'
    })
</script>
```

Tercer ejercicio.

Lo mismo que el segundo. Iterar sobre la coleccion de h2. Ademas no existe una propiedad llamada fontChange sino fontFamily

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 
 function FontChange(){
    var hdos = document.getElementsByTagName('h2')
    Array.from(titulos).forEach( (h2) => {
        h2.style.fontFamily = 'Arial'
    })
 }
   
</script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, pero sigue sin funcionarme...seguramente entregue el trabajo con éstos 3 items sin funcionar y que me explique el profesor que está mal, porque incluso he copiado código letra por letra de tutoriales y no funciona.